# Add Custom Data fields to VM during VM offer to Azure Marketplace

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

I'm unable to find documentation related to adding custom data fields to VM while creating a VM offer to Azure Marketplace

I have gone through documentation which talks about custom data and how I can use them while provisioning a VM but nothing describes how I can set it up while making a VM offer in azure marketplace

Ref : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-data-and-cloud-init-on-windows-azure/

Is there any documentation that talks about asking certain custom data fields from the customer before deploying the VM from azure marketplace?

Answer (score 1):

This [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-customdata) allows you to create a Virtual Machine with Custom Data. This template also deploys a Storage Account, Virtual Network, Public IP addresses and a Network Interface.
You can verify the Custom Data in the file /var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt.